# Can't get all the tabular contents from a webpage using requests

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping

I've created a script in python to parse the tabular content from a website. My script now can parse the content from it's landing page. However, there is a `NEXT PAGE` button at the bottom of that page which unfolds 50 more results when gets clicked and so on.

[Website address](https://indiarailinfo.com/trains/passenger/0/0/0/0)

I've tried with (scrapes first 50 results):

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site_link = 'https://indiarailinfo.com/trains/passenger/0/0/0/0'

res = requests.get(site_link)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
for items in soup.select("div[style='line-height:20px;']"):
    tds = [elem.get_text(strip=True) for elem in items.select("div")]
    print(tds)
```

***How can I get all the tabular contents from that page exhausting the next page button using requests?***

PS I know how to unfold the content using selenium, so solution related to any browser simulator is not what I'm after.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Clicking the next button is actually doing XHR to https://indiarailinfo.com/trains/passenger/0/1?i=1&&kkk=1571329558457

```
<button class="nextbtn" onclick="javascript:getNextTrainListPageBare($(this).parent(),'/trains/passenger/0/1?i=1&amp;');"><div>NEXT PAGE<br>the next 50 Trains will appear below</div></button>
```

So all you have to do is get the data under 'onclick' ,compose a url and do HTTP GET using requests.

The returned data will look like this

https://pastebin.com/Nk0E5vHH

Now just use BeautifulSoup and extract the data you need.

Code below (replace 10 with the number that you need)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

site_link = 'https://indiarailinfo.com/trains/passenger/0/{}'

for x in range(10):
    url = site_link.format(x)
    res = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text,"lxml")
    print('Data for url: {}'.format(url))
    for items in soup.select("div[style='line-height:20px;']"):
        tds = [elem.get_text(strip=True) for elem in items.select("div")]
        print(tds)
```

Comment: I also have noticed that. The problem is I can't merge the existing logic that I've already applied with the one you have spotted to get them all.

Comment: Perfectly working!!! I got confused to see this type of portion `i=1&i=1&&kkk=1571333169282` getting appended to the next page url in every iteration.

Comment: Yes... The kkk points to epoch times (you can take the value pointed by each kkk and translate it to date )